Mock a call to a Repository that uses Ardalis Specification
I have a generic Repository (RepositoryBase) that gets queried using a specification
Specification
public sealed class ProductByIdSpec : SingleResultSpecification<Product>
{
    public ProductByIdSpec (int id)
    {
        Query
     
            .Where(p => p.Id == id);
    }

  
}

I then used NSubstitute to mock the repository in unittests.
  _productRepository = Substitute.For<IReadRepositoryBase<Product>>();

I can use the generic matcher to return a Product

    _assetRepository.SingleOrDefaultAsync( 
            
            Arg.Any<ProductByIdSpec>())
        .Returns(product);


The Product is then retrieved by calling

_productRepository.SingleOrDefaultAsync(new ProductByIdSpec(42));

I dont find a way to set up a matcher that takes into account the id
I tried
_productRepository.SingleOrDefaultAsync( Arg.Is(new ProductByIdSpec(42))
         .Returns(product);

But this does return null with

_productRepository.SingleOrDefaultAsync(new ProductByIdSpec(42));

I get it that at some point there needs to be a comparison of two instances of new ProductByIdSpec(42) which does not work for me.
I tried top use a lambda but dont find a way for getting the "42" in the object new ProductByIdSpec(42)
_productRepository.SingleOrDefaultAsync( 
            
            Arg.Is<ProductByIdSpec>(x => x.SearchCriterias ??????))
        .Returns(product);

Is there a way to use Ardalis Specification together with NSubstitute for the case I showed?
